# How to Cancel a ProgressDialog without call Dismiss?

Tags: android, progressdialog, toast, dismiss

The cancel's Toast and the dismiss's Toast appears when I press the Cancel Button. How can I solve this?. Thanks.

EDIT : I need a Toast when push the Cancel Button, and I need another different Toast when the ProgressDialog finish correctly (when I dismiss it). But now, I have the correct Toast when ProgressDialog finish correctly, but when I push the Cancel Button the result is both Toast. (It's a ProgressDialog with a bar that is incremented by 5 to complete).Sorry for my english :S

```
myPd_bar.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancelled.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }});

            myPd_bar.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            myPd_bar.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                { 
                    myPd_bar.cancel();
                }
            });

            myPd_bar.show();
```

**EDIT2 : The final solution :**

```
private int sw = 0;

myPd_bar.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {

                        if (sw==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Envio Realizado Correctamente.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        myPd_bar.dismiss();
                            sw=0;
                        }
                });


                //Botón Cancelar.
                myPd_bar.setButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    { 
                        sw = 1;
                        //Mostramos el mensaje al cancelar.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Envío Cancelado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        myPd_bar.cancel();
                    }
                });

                myPd_bar.show();
```

Comment: Do you really need this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

> public void cancel ()
>
> Cancel the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).

If you don't want both to show, just use `dismiss()`. When you cancel, it first dismisses, then cancels the dialog. This causes both listeners to fire. There's really no way around it, unless you wanted to override `cancel()` itself and implement your own method. I can't see a good reason to do that, though.

Also, I second Egor's comment. If you *really* need to do it "for a practice", explain exactly what it is you're trying to do.

**Edit:** From your comment below, I'd recommend not using the listeners at all. If all you need to do on dismiss/cancel is show toasts, just create the toasts directly.

```
myPd_bar.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myPd_bar.cancel();
    }
});

void dismissDialog(Context myContext)
{
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "Done.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myPd_bar.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I need a Toast when push the Cancel Button, and I need another different Toast when the ProgressDialog finish correctly (when I dismiss it). But now, I have the correct Toast when ProgressDialog finish correctly, but when I push the Cancel Button the result is both Toast. (It's a ProgressDialog with a bar that is incremented by 5 to complete).Sorry for my english :S.

Comment: I see, updated the answer. Unless you need to do something besides toasts, it would be easier to skip the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling

```
myPd_bar.show();
```

do this,

```
myPd_bar.setCancelable(true);
```

More info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)